# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Direct Update on iOS fails with Update Failed - Failed processing application update file

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

For iOS devices, the Direct Update flow is triggered but fails when unpacking the update archive.
Note that for Android devices, the process works correctly and updates are pushed to the client apps successfully.

The Direct Update prompt is triggered correctly when checksums between the content of initial installed .ipa build is different than new uploaded .wlappp to AppCenter.
Both AppCenter server and WL client logs show the connections is ok and package download successful.

The process failes when unzipping the updated resource package with logged error : **"Fatal error updating application. Can't open downloaded zip file."** (below and attached).

We have tried both alternatives with same outcome.

- Enabling the flag in initOptions.js

> ```
> connectOnStartup : true,      
> onConnectionFailure: function (){alert("Worklight server connection failed. Direct Update is not possible.");wlCommonInit();},
> ```

- Triggering connect in wlCommonInit()

  > ```
  > WL.Client.connect({
  >     onSuccess: function(){WL.Logger.error("OK");},
  >     onFailure: function(){WL.Logger.error("FAIL");}
  > });
  > ```

iOS Logs:

> ```
> 2014-08-09 10:25:28.974 SMC[1500:60b] [INFO] [wl.client] WL.Client.connect onConnectSuccess ENTERING
> 2014-08-09 10:25:28.981 SMC[1500:60b] [DEBUG] [NONE] wlclient connect success
> 2014-08-09 10:25:29.096 SMC[1500:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['Notification'] took '107.535889' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
> 2014-08-09 10:26:19.976 SMC[1500:60b] [ERROR] [NONE] Update checksum is 3782542690
> 2014-08-09 10:26:19.988 SMC[1500:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['NetworkDetector'] took '13.082031' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
> 2014-08-09 10:26:19.990 SMC[1500:60b] [ERROR] [NONE] In Progress checksum is 3782542690
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.002 SMC[1500:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['NetworkDetector'] took '11.927979' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.004 SMC[1500:60b] [DEBUG] [NONE] Request [https://{appceneter_hostname}:443/worklight/apps/services/api/SMC/iphone/setup]
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.014 SMC[1500:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['NetworkDetector'] took '10.286133' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.041 SMC[1500:60b] Requesting bytes starting from 0
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.042 SMC[1500:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['WebResourcesDownloader'] took '25.979004' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.106 SMC[1500:60b] Start downloading update file.
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.110 SMC[1500:60b] Temp update file is /var/mobile/Applications/2DEEED98-E567-4ABB-AD41-BE74EF28A014/Library/tempUpdateFile
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.116 SMC[1500:60b] Length of updateFileBase64String before appending 0 
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.118 SMC[1500:60b] Length of updateFileBase64String after appending 0 
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.247 SMC[1500:60b] Temp update file is /var/mobile/Applications/2DEEED98-E567-4ABB-AD41-BE74EF28A014/Library/tempUpdateFile
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.279 SMC[1500:60b] Length of updateFileBase64String before appending 0 
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.281 SMC[1500:60b] Length of updateFileBase64String after appending 0 
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.316 SMC[1500:60b] [DEBUG] [NONE] response [https://{appcenter_hostname}:443/worklight/apps/services/api/SMC/iphone/setup] success: 
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.326 SMC[1500:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['NetworkDetector'] took '10.586914' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.328 SMC[1500:60b] [DEBUG] [NONE] defaultOptions:onSuccess
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.339 SMC[1500:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['NetworkDetector'] took '11.760010' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.386 SMC[1500:60b] Temp update file is /var/mobile/Applications/2DEEED98-E567-4ABB-AD41-BE74EF28A014/Library/tempUpdateFile
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.391 SMC[1500:60b] Length of updateFileBase64String before appending 0 
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.392 SMC[1500:60b] Length of updateFileBase64String after appending 0 
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.496 SMC[1500:60b] Temp update file is /var/mobile/Applications/2DEEED98-E567-4ABB-AD41-BE74EF28A014/Library/tempUpdateFile
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.501 SMC[1500:60b] Length of updateFileBase64String before appending 0 
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.502 SMC[1500:60b] Length of updateFileBase64String after appending 0 
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.544 SMC[1500:60b] Finished downloading.
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.545 SMC[1500:60b] Deleting file
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.547 SMC[1500:60b] File deleted
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.548 SMC[1500:60b] webViewDidFinishLoad: Length of updateFileBase64String before appending 0 
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.550 SMC[1500:60b] webViewDidFinishLoad: Length of updateFileBase64String after appending 0 
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.551 SMC[1500:60b] Setting progress
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.553 SMC[1500:60b] Starting to unpack
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.556 SMC[1500:60b] Decoding base 64
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.558 SMC[1500:60b] Unzipping
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.562 SMC[1500:60b] Zip file created
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.570 SMC[1500:60b] Fatal error updating application. Can't open downloaded zip file.
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.572 SMC[1500:60b] Warning: Attempt to dismiss from view controller <CDVMainViewController: 0x15630070> while a presentation or dismiss is in progress!
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.586 SMC[1500:60b] Releasing downloadUpdateFileUiWebView
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.631 SMC[1500:60b] THREAD WARNING: ['Notification'] took '39.161133' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
> 2014-08-09 10:26:20.636 SMC[1500:60b] Temp update file is /var/mobile/Applications/2DEEED98-E567-4ABB-AD41-BE74EF28A014/Library/tempUpdateFile
> 2014-08-09 10:26:21.236 SMC[1500:60b] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <CDVMainViewController: 0x15630070>.
> ```

Comment: DannySSS, is this still an issue with the latest 6.1.0.2 iFix?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have updated your Server and Studio installations to the very latest 6.1.0.02 iFix release, as related Direct Update fixes were made. The iFix can be obtained from [IBM Fix Central](http://www-933.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/).

If it does not work for you, still, update the question with updated logs.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue when I build the iOS hybrid file using windows machine.
And problem solved when I build using Mac machine.
Try to rebuild the .wlapp file for iOS and redeploy it to WL console and test the direct update again.

Hope this help.